# TypeError: Cannot read property 'settDate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

On a click event I am trying to pass data from one componentto another in Angular and my components are like below

Parent Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reporting-filter',
  templateUrl: './reporting-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reporting-filter.component.scss'],
  providers: [ProjectShipmentService]
})

export class ReportingFilterComponent implements DoCheck {

  @ViewChild(TjlShipdateFilterComponent, {static: false})
  private tjl: TjlShipdateFilterComponent;

  finalResult: ShipDateFilterModel[];

  click() {
    this.elem = this.getResultOnFilter(this.firstSelection, this.secondSelection);
      this.tjl.settDate(this.finalResult);
  }
   ........}
```

Child Component is like

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-tjl-shipdate-filter',
  providers: [ProjectShipmentService],
  templateUrl: './tjl-shipdate-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tjl-shipdate-filter.component.scss']
})
export class TjlShipdateFilterComponent implements DoCheck {
 tljShipDate: ShipDateFilterModel[];
  @Input() settDate(e: ShipDateFilterModel[]) {
    this.tljShipDate = e;
  }
......}
```

reporting-filter.component.html

```
      <dxi-item  [ratio]="1">
              <dx-button (onClick)="click()" style="padding: 1vw 3vw 1.5vw 3vw; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Filter</dx-button>
      </dxi-item>
```

But when the button is clicked and the 'this.tjl.settDate(this.finalResult);' is executed in the parent component. I get the:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'settDate' of undefined

Not sure if we are missing anything here

[image]

Comment: setData or setDate ??

Comment: Set**t**Date - ?

Comment: @Chellappan @Input() is just wat I have in the above code

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi That was a typo, I updated it

Comment: @Rob That was a typo, I updated it

Comment: can you share the html of app-reporting-filter component

Comment: @LeeTaylor settDate() is the name

Comment: @Sanket Added the html code

Comment: You haven't included the TjlShipdateFilterComponent component in your html. Angular wont be able to find the child using ViewChild and hence its giving you error  ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'settDate' of undefined``` as settDate is being called on undefined.

Comment: @Sanket How do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling methods on the child component you can pass data and bind to the Input setter. You need to add a space between `set` and `Data` to do this

```
 @Input() set Data(e: ShipDateFilterModel[]) {
    this.tljShipDate = e;
  }
```

Then in the parent component you will want to create a variable which can be passed down, e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reporting-filter',
  template: ` 
              <button (click)="click()">Click Me</button>
              <app-tjl-shipdate-filter [data]="tjlData" ></app-tjl-shipdate-filter>
  `,
  providers: [ProjectShipmentService]
})

export class ReportingFilterComponent {
  @ViewChild(TjlShipdateFilterComponent, {static: false})
  private tjl: TjlShipdateFilterComponent;
  private tjlData: any
  click() {
    this.tjlData = 'example data to pass'
  }
}
```

You can find a working stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r24zqd

Comment: The stackblitz solution is not working. When I click there nothing is showing up

Comment: No there is nothing to show as you did not specify anything you wanted to do with the data once passed, nor the additional functions used, nor the relevant component templates (which is fine, the challenge here was to get the data moving between the components correctly).

So if you're happy with the answer you can mark it as correct, if not you can either try to re-specify the original question or create a new post, or ask further questions here.